# Add dynamic checkbox to listview on longclick item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I need to add check boxes for all the items in the List view even if one item is long clicked in the list. Should I implement onItemLongClickListener in Activity class or should I implement in Adapter class getView method? I tried following in Adapter class :

```
chkItem = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chkLvItem);
    listTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            checkable=true;
            chkItem.setVisibility(checkable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            displayAllCheckbox(checkable);
            return true;
        }
    });
 public void displayAllCheckbox(boolean checkable)
{
    this.checkable = checkable;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't add checkbox from out of nowhere.

best way from my view is this:

1. add a checkbox to listview costum layout
2. make it Gone
3. then make it Visible whenever you want

Comment: I am already following the same approach which you said. But the problem is when I long press on an textview item , I get only 1 checkbox but I need to have checkboxes for all items in list that time.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to add checkbox on Long press of Item click ?Currently I am adding on long press of textview.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the following.Hope it helps someone :)

```
final CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chkLvItem);

    if(checkable==true)
    {   
        chkItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        chkItem.setChecked(checkBoxState[pos]);

    }


    textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            if(!checkable)
            {
                chkItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                checkBoxState[pos]=true;
                chkItem.setChecked(checkBoxState[pos]);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"longclick");
                checkable=true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```